# How can i use Hangfire in Multi-Tenant App?

Tags: .net, hangfire

Currently i have single tenant app, that uses hangfire as background job.

Now we need to migrate this into multitenant architecture
Like

1. One App
2. One Db ( with clientId Filter)

Now we need to use hangfire jobs as multi-tenant architecture.

I am not able to address two issues:

1. How can I utilize a different job storage database for Hangfire based on the tenant ID?
2. How i retrive the correct TenantId to Run the JOb

I am quite new to Hangfire so wondering if any expert would like to jump in and provide me with the suggestions and best practices tips.